# Gutenberg editor disapeared

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

My wordpress installation corrupted (perhaps during a plugin upgrade) in a way that the Gutenberg editor does not show up and I only see an HTML editor (plain text box). Before, I was using Gutenberg.

[plain HTML editor instead of Gutenberg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ue8T.png)

- I use Neve template
- I minimized the plugin set to my minimal need (`Advanced WordPress Backgrounds` and `Everest Forms`) to eliminate the interference, but it didn't recover.
- The problem is both for pages and posts.
- I see no javascript exception (Chrome).

Any idea how to fix this?

As a response to the answer below: I don't see an option to switch to visual editor: [no "Visual editor" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B14vD.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may have accidentally gone into Code Editor view. This can be toggled by the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M` or changed back via the Settings Menu and selecting **Visual Editor**

[image: Settings Menu]

Hopefully this resolves your issue..

**UPDATE:**
I installed the Neve theme on a fresh WordPress 5.9.2 installation and found it actually does change the location of the Visual/Code Editor menu, see screenshot below:

[image: Settings Menu - Neve]

As you're on Mac, the shortcut will be slightly different: `⌘+Shift+Alt+M`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have such option.
I will leave a screenshot in the original messages, because here I can't link one.

The keyboard shortcut does not work either.

Comment: @Jirka What your screenshot shows is the HTML view of the Gutenberg editor, so S.Walsh is right.

Comment: @Jirka Please see updated answer above, Neve theme does actually change location of the menu and the shortcut is slightly different on Mac.

Comment: See my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B14vD.png
I don't have any `EDITOR` section in the menu.

Comment: @Jirka I would try disabling all plugins, then one by one, re-enabling them to find which one is causing the issue. Also check the server log to see if there is any error.